# Как запретить вывод на главной странице в Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Добрый день!

Я недавно начал заниматься Magento и поэтому у меня небольшой опыт разработки приложений на ней. У меня вопрос: у меня есть кастомный фильтр по брендам, он нормально работает на внутренних страницах сайта, а на главной выводится ошибка, как мне сделать, чтобы блок с фильтром не выводился на главной странице. На данный момент блок с кодом имеет шаблон right.phtml и подключается в catalog.xml.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как в Magento убрать блок с главной страницы](http://magento-forum.ru/topic/248/)

[Как в Magento убирать блоки посредством макетных правил](http://magento-forum.ru/topic/978/)